# Which external jars do I have to import in my first eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I`m following this article https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html  but I don`t know which jars should I import at step 5 because I am using eclipse kepler.Could someone tell me what should I import instead org.eclipse.ui_2.0.0-> workbench.jar and " org.eclipse.swt.win32_2.0.0->ws->win32  contains swt.jar"?

Comment: The latest version of Eclipse is Neon (4.6), Kepler is old. That tutorial is so old that it is no longer valid. Find something newer, the tutorials on http://www.vogella.com/ are generally very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an outdated version of Eclipse and an outdated tutorial.
Updating to "Eclipse neon" is a choice but you should **really** look at a different tutorial.

The Eclipse documentation offers an [example](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Ffirstplugin.htm) and a [step by step](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.rse.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Ftutorial%2FpdeProject.html).

Here are some other sources, the IBM one is from 2008:

- [IBM: Plug-in development 101, Part 1: The fundamentals](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-eclipse-plugindev1/)
- [Wideskills: Eclipse plugin tutorial](http://www.wideskills.com/eclipse-plugin-tutorial)